# save model with foreign key in django

Tags: django

I have models for eg like this.

```
class Mp3(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    artist=models.ForeignKey('Artist')
```

and Here is how the Artist models looks like:

alert(1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```
class Mp3(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: do you want to save model in django with foreign key in views

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with

```
class Mp3(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```